# How can I send back Bundle in Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have created Login form and when login success. It will go to `MainActivity.java`
in `MainActivity` have a `button` to go to Account Settings with `intent` sending username and password. Like this:

```
editu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditUser.class);
                    i.putExtra("id",mUser.getId());
                    i.putExtra("username",mUser.getUsername());
                    i.putExtra("pass",mUser.getPassword());
                    startActivity(i);
                    //finish();
        }
    });
```

And in `EditUser.class` has the `Bundle` to get information like:

```
Bundle args = getIntent().getExtras();
```

But when I finished managing on account I want to go back to home (MainActivity) by tab on `home button`<- (picture in link below). It will go out of the Application.

[Link is here](http://image.ohozaa.com/view2/yjtLUhK6cKDg44LA)

And I realized that because of this condition in `MainActivity`

```
if (null == args) {
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.welcome_error_message),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }
```

But I don't know, how to send an `intent` back from `EditUser.class` to `MainActivity.class`
I have tried the following code, but it didn't work. (Code on EditUser)

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    i.putExtra(User.Column.ID,mUser.getId());
    i.putExtra(User.Column.USERNAME,mUser.getUsername());
    i.putExtra(User.Column.PASSWORD,mUser.getPassword());
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: first correct your condition check condition this way ( if(args == null) ) and save data into preference after login then use it when ever you need.

Comment: Call child activity by `startActivityForResult()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to call the `MainActivity` using `startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);`. Then you do like the following code:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        // Do something

    }

}
```

EDIT:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pedido);

    // You have to enable the home button on action bar doing the following
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

}
```

Then you must also do:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {

        finish();

        return true;
    }
    else {
        return MenuActionBar.optionsItemSelected(this, null, item)
                ? true : super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Comment: Is `onBackPressed() ` it for back button on label?

Comment: No. That method is only for back button. I'm gonna edit my answer to show you how you can do so.

Comment: No, only the `onActivityResult` has to be in `MainActivity`. The other ones have to be in your `EditUser`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [onActivityResult()](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) for this.
set data to intent and pass it with click of back button click.